# Linq to Xml to Datagridview

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, linq-to-xml

Right, starting to go crazy here. I have the following code:

```
var query = (from c in db.Descendants("Customer")
                             select c.Elements());
                dgvEditCusts.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

In this, db relates to an XDocument.Load call. How can I get the data into the DataGridView?

Just thought I should mention: it returns a completely blank dgv.

Not that the XML should matter too much, but here's an example:

```
<Root>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerNumber>1</CustomerNumber>
    <EntryDate>2010-04-13T21:59:46.4642+01:00</EntryDate>
    <Name>Customer Name</Name>
    <Address>Address</Address>
    <PostCode1>AB1</PostCode1>
    <PostCode2>2XY</PostCode2>
    <TelephoneNumber>0123456789</TelephoneNumber>
    <MobileNumber>0123456789</MobileNumber>
    <AlternativeNumber></AlternativeNumber>
    <EmailAddress>email@address.com</EmailAddress>
  </Customer>
</Root>
```

Comment: Can you please provide example xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, never mind, I've worked out the answer to my own question eventually. Here's the code for anyone else that may have this problem:

```
var query = from c in db.Descendants("Customer")
                            select new
                            {
                                CustomerNumber = Convert.ToInt32((string)c.Element("CustomerNumber").Value),
                                Name = (string)c.Element("Name").Value,
                                Address = (string)c.Element("Address").Value,
                                Postcode = (string)c.Element("PostCode1").Value + " " + c.Element("PostCode2").Value
                            };
                dgvEditCusts.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Was just about to post the same thing :) one thing I did notice, that I can't explain is that the ToList of the .Elements() query is returing an XContainer.GetElements() object so it seems that .ToList() is not materialising the data as one would expect. Glad you got this sorted.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `db.Descendants("Customer")` you are returning ONLY the elements that have the name `Customer` in it. NOT it's children. See [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

So when you call `c.Elements()` it is trying to get the Customer's child elements which don't exist b/c they were filtered out.

I think it might work if you drop the `Customer` filtering.