# c# linq to xml dynamic query

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Right, bit of a strange question; I have been doing some linq to XML work recently (see my other recent posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633745/linq-to-xml-to-datagridview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630192/c-check-an-element-exists-while-using-linq-to-xml)).

Basically, I want to be able to create a query that checks whether a textbox is null before it's value is included in the query, like so:

```
XDocument db = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var query = (from vals in db.Descendants("Customer")
            where (if(textbox1.Text != "") {vals.Element("CustomerID") == Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text) } || 
                  if(textbox2.Text != "") {vals.Element("Name") == textbox2.Text})
            select vals).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the normal Boolean operators && and ||:

```
XDocument db = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var query = (from vals in db.Descendants("Customer")
            where (textbox1.Text != "" && 
               vals.Element("CustomerID") == Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text)) || 
               (textbox2.Text != "" && vals.Element("Name") == textbox2.Text)
            select vals).ToList();
```

That's just a direct translation of the original code - but I think you'll want a cast from `vals.Element("CustomerID")` to `int`, and you don't really want to convert `textbox1.Text` on every iteration, I'm sure. You also need to convert the "name" `XElement` to a string. How about this:

```
int? customerId = null;
if (textbox1.Text != "")
{
    customerId = int.Parse(textbox1.Text);
}

XDocument db = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
var query = (from vals in db.Descendants("Customer")
             where (customerId != null && 
                (int) vals.Element("CustomerID") == customerId) ||
                (textbox2.Text != "" && 
                 (string) vals.Element("Name") == textbox2.Text)
             select vals).ToList();
```

Alternatively, you could separate out the two parts of the query and "union" the results together. Or - preferably IMO - you could build the query more dynamically:

```
var query = db.Descendants("Customer");
if (textbox1.Text != null)
{
    int customerId = int.Parse(textbox1.Text);
    query = query.Where(x => (int) x.Element("CustomerID") == customerId);
}

if (textbox2.Text != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x => (string) x.Element("Name") == textbox2.Text);
}
List<XElement> results = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Fantastic again Jon. I've already cased out to values as you mentioned in the second option, just was using the code above to make things more simple. Thank you very much again!